# No match for operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a class with overloading `operator<<` but it keeps giving me that error. Here is my code:

```
//Course.h
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Course& course);

//Course.cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Course& course)
{
os << course.courseCode << " " << course.credit << " " << course.section " " << endl;
return os;
}
```

Here is the all .h

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Course
{
    public:
        Course();
        Course(string code,int credit,int section);
        virtual ~Course();
        string getCourseCode();
        void setCourseCode(string code);
        int getCredit();
        void setCredit(int credit);
        int getSection();
        void setSection(int section);
        bool operator==(Course &course);
        bool operator!=(Course &course);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Course& course);

    private:
        string courseCode;
        int credit,section;
};

#endif // COURSE_H
```

And here is the some part of .cpp

```
#include "Course.h"
.
.
//Other functions' implementations
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Course& course)
{
    os << course.courseCode << " " << course.credit << " " << course.section " " << endl;
}
```

I changed parameters as `const` but nothing changed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you declared your friend declaration in your class?

Comment: Could you post a complete MWE, including how you call operator<< ? One immediate possibility that comes to find: you've defined operator<< taking a non-const reference to a Course object, whereas you may need one taking a const reference.

Comment: @Papipone yes it is in my class.

Comment: @jwimberley sorry but what is MWE :/

Comment: @Mystro The following link describe what it is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mystro Could you show your class declaration and definition?

Comment: @Papipone i edited the question

Comment: @Mystro include iostream in your header.

Comment: @Papipone thank you man now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a following sample on how to overload the flux operator:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Test& t);

private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Test& t)
{
    stream << "Test::a " << t.a << "\nTest::b " << t.b << '\n';
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    Test t(20, 40);
    std::cout << t;

    return 0;
}
```